# Update table from temp table with dynamic columns names in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to update a table from the data of a temp table.

There is one id column that need to match between the 2 tables for update the good rows.

The thing is that except the id, i need to update some other column but i won't know the name of the column in the temp table because the creation of the temp table is also dynamic.

So i need to dynamically find which column name match between the two tables and then update the right column from the temp table to the other table.

```
SELECT *
FROM tempdb.sys.columns
WHERE object_id = Object_id('tempdb..#AccountId');
```

with that i can get the name of the column of the temp table.

But after i can't go further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the matching column name into a variable and use T-SQL to construct a query using the name stored in the variable.

```
DECLARE @col_name varchar(128), @sql_stmt varchar(1000)
SET @col_name = (
    SELECT name
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns
    WHERE object_id = Object_id('tempdb..#YourTempTableName')
    and name in (
        SELECT column_name
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'YourTableName'
        )
    )

SET @sql_stmt = ('
    UPDATE YourTableName 
    SET ' + @col_name + ' = t2.' + @col_name +'
    FROM YourTableName t1
    JOIN #YourTempTableName t2 on t1.id = t2.id'
    )

EXEC @sql_stmt
```

Replace `#YourTempTableName` and `YourTableName` with the actual table names. Please note that this approach only works if you have only one column name between the two tables that matches. If it finds more than one match, this query will throw an error. Also, this assumes that both id columns in your tables are called 'id', if not you will have to update the join statement with the actual id column names.